# Jolt filter - keep JSON structure even if node is empty

Tags: json, filter, jolt

**Hi guys,**
I'm working on some complex filter which is configured to work for two different JSONs, the difference is that one of them has one more node. Everything works fine except in one corner case  and I have difficulties with keeping the JSONs structure.

***Here is my case:***

**JSON 1:**

```json
{
    "header": {
      "something": "something"
    },
    "payload": {
      "decisions": [
        {
          "sequenceId": "1",
          "decision": "serviceToDelete",
          "something": "something"
        }
      ],
      "elements": [
        {
          "serviceName": "serviceToDelete",
          "something": "something"
        }
      ]
    },
  "moreStuff": []
}
```

**JSON 2:**

```json
{
  "message": {
    "header": {
      "something": "something"
    },
    "payload": {
      "decisions": [
        {
          "sequenceId": "1",
          "decision": "serviceToDelete",
          "something": "something"
        }
      ],
      "elements": [
        {
          "serviceName": "serviceToDelete",
          "something": "something"
        }
      ]
    },
    "someStuff": {
      "otherStuff": "stuff"
    }
  },
  "moreStuff": []
}
```

**FILTER**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "message": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "payload": {
          "*": "&",
          "decisions": {
            "*": {
              "decision": {
                "serviceToDelete": null,
                "*": {
                  "@2": "&6.&4"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "elements": {
            "*": {
              "serviceName": {
                "serviceToDelete": null,
                "*": {
                  "@2": "&6.&4"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "workflow": {
          "*\\].*": {
            "serviceToDelete": null,
            "*": {
              "@1": "&3.&(2,1).&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "workflow": {
        "*": {
          "*ServiceId": {
            "@1": "&3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "w*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "message.&3.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "message": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "decisions": "&1.payload.decisions",
        "elements": "&1.payload.elements"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payload": {
        "*": "&",
        "decisions": {
          "*": {
            "decision": {
              "serviceToDelete": null,
              "*": {
                "@2": "decisions"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "elements": {
          "*": {
            "serviceName": {
              "serviceToDelete": null,
              "*": {
                "@2": "elements"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
    "decisions": "payload.decisions",
    "elements": "payload.elements"
    }
  }
]
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```json
{
  "header" : {
    "something" : "something"
  },
  "moreStuff" : [ ]
}
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```json
{
  "message" : {
    "header" : {
      "something" : "something"
    },
    "someStuff" : {
      "otherStuff" : "stuff"
    }
  },
  "moreStuff" : [ ]
}
```

As you see here after filter the this node is missing:

```json
 "payload": {
      "decisions": [],
      "elements": []
    }
```

I want to keep the JSON structure. So, this node will be there and just be empty. Like this:

**EXPECTED 1:**

```json
{
    "header": {
        "something": "something"
    },
    "payload": {
        "decisions": [],
        "elements": []
    },
    "moreStuff": []
}
```

**EXPECTED 2:**

```json
 {
    "message": {
        "header": {
            "something": "something"
        },
        "payload": {
            "decisions": [],
            "elements": []
        },
        "someStuff": {
            "otherStuff": "stuff"
        }
    },
    "moreStuff": []
}
```

Keep the "payload" node empty also with "decisions" and "elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add a **default** transformation spec along with a new **shift** spec such as

```json
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "decisions": [],
          "elements": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "header": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "payload": "&"
      }
    }
  }
```

to the bottom of the current spec, just before the closing square bracket.

Comment: correct @barbaros , but when I put the default operation you gave the `payload` node is going inside `header` that I see in [link](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) when I test it.

Comment: OK, I understood what you've meant now :) Just fixed @dimitar.bonchev

Comment: Outstanding @barbaros. Thank you this is the case I was looking for. Wish u all the best! :)